# Disposing resource inside spock feature method at arbitrary places

Tags: groovy, spock

Inside a spock test we want to create a resource and make sure its disposed correctly regardless of the outcome of the test result.

We tried the approach below. But spock is not executing tests when the test code is wrapped inside a closure.

```groovy
import spock.lang.Specification

class ExampleSpec extends Specification {

    def wrapperFunction(Closure cl) {
        try {
            cl()
        } finally {
            // do custom stuff
        }
    }

    def "test wrapped in closure"() {
        wrapperFunction {
            expect:
            1 == 1
            println "will not execute!"
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best approach on creating and disposing a resource inside a spock test.

`setup()` and `cleanup()` are not viable solutions since creating and disposing should be possible at arbitrary points inside the feature method.

Comment: It's difficult to guess what you're testing in this example. Are you trying to assert that `cl` is invoked?

Comment: I assume the error is something along the lines, that Spock is complaining about the structure here?  The no-smart-options-remaing-approach could be moving `expect:` out and writing regular asserts inside that closure.

Comment: what kind of resources are those?

Comment: @YuriG They are wiremock stubs. 
AT jaco0646 Its not about the invocation of cl. Its just that cl would be an important part of the using pattern we want to use.

Comment: Ehm... I, kinda, don't really get how stubs could be an actual I/O resourses you need  clean up afterwards. That's a mock, after all, it shouldn't have to mess with external resourses, that's the whole point of mocking. Can you elaborate more on these "resourses" & what exact part needs disposition handle beyond what's already provided by JVM out of the box? Cause I have a feeling you're pursuit might turn out to be absolutely unnecessary

Comment: @YuriG Stubs in the context of a wiremock server are endpoints that return defined data. E.g a order confirmation for a POST /order endpoint. These stubs need cleaning up since the server contains these persistent endpoints as long as they are not deleted / cleaned up. Read more about it http://wiremock.org/docs/stubbing/

Comment: @YuriG Your are correct. Removing the stub at the wiremock server is the goal. My suspicion is there is no better approach to using setup: and cleanup: and a [using pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) style is probably not possible

Comment: Oh, man... that just adds to confusion, honestly. First, when you talking about "creating/opening resources" in Java context - everyone immediately think "I/O streams" or alike. Then, start to wonder "what's wrong with using Cloaseable here?!". Don't do that again, I beg you.

Comment: Now, regarding your ACTUAL situation: why do you bother about the thing whatsoever, I wonder even more? On the test execution site, these facades to the server mocks are dirt cheap, why would one ever want to dispose them explicitly, beyond what JVM would do anyways at the end of test life (which is pretty short, as long as JUnit is actually running the Spock stuff, and it spans a separate instance of a test class for each @test method executed)? The actual server implementation of the mocks doesn't differ much, it's pretty substantial & its resource consumption is negligible.

Comment: Having the fact that mocks are overrideable on WireMock server - I don't see why one would even bother to delete each individual mock after (not to say during) each individual test method? Just do reset all operation in the overall test suite tearDown, and you'd be perfectly fine. All that said - don't you feel you're overengineering the whole thing just out of NOTHING?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `setup` and `cleanup` block inside of the test case (feature method) like this:

```
class ReleaseResourcesSpec extends Specification {
    void 'Resources are released'() {
        setup:
        def stream = new FileInputStream('/etc/hosts')

        when:
        throw new IllegalStateException('test')

        then:
        true

        cleanup:
        stream.close()
        println 'stream was closed'
    }
}
```

Code from the `cleanup` block is always executed although the test fails or if there is any exception. See the result of the above example:
[image]

So it is similar to `setup()` and `cleanup()` methods but in this case you can have different setup and clean up code for each feature method.

Comment: Indeed a viable solution we currently use in a similar form. The need to store the resource inside a dedicated variable and additional code needed to free the resource inbetween (which we sometimes need) made us come up with the question above. @cgrim any way to avoid the seperated setup: and cleanup: section and create something that is more like this pattern the [using pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)